mybatis nested object mapping xml
i have a question which have been bug me for many days.
I am using mybatis to coding spring security. All i want to do is fetch all users along with users'role. so i am trying to using mybatis nested object mapping but when i writing this function always popup argument type mismatch error. Could you tell me what is wrong with my code. it will be graceful.
this is my tables.
create table tbl_role
(
    role_id   int auto_increment
        primary key,
    role_name varchar(100) null
);

create table tbl_user
(
    username                   varchar(255) not null
        primary key,
    email                      varchar(255) not null,
    password                   varchar(255) not null,
    birth_date                 datetime(6)  not null,
    gender                     varchar(50)  null,
    is_account_non_expired     bit          not null,
    is_account_non_locked      bit          not null,
    is_credentials_non_expired bit          not null,
    is_enabled                 bit          not null,
    last_login_date            datetime(6)  null,
    create_date                datetime(6)  null,
    last_update_date           datetime(6)  null
);

create table tbl_role_user_map
(
    username varchar(100) null,
    role_id  int          null,
    constraint fk_tbl_role_user_map_tbl_role
        foreign key (role_id) references tbl_role (role_id),
    constraint fk_tbl_role_user_map_tbl_user
        foreign key (username) references tbl_user (username)
);


this is my mybatis xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.learningspringsecurity.dao.UserMapper">
    <insert id="insertUser">
        INSERT INTO tbl_user(
            USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, BIRTH_DATE, GENDER,
            IS_ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED, IS_ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED,
            IS_CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED, IS_ENABLED, CREATE_DATE
        ) VALUES (
                     #{username}, #{email}, #{password}, #{birthDate}, #{gender},
                     #{isAccountNonExpired}, #{isAccountNonLocked},
                     #{isCredentialsNonExpired}, #{isEnabled}, #{createDate}
                 )
    </insert>

    <resultMap id="userRoleResultMap" type="com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.UserView">
        <!-- User fields -->
        <id property="username" column="username" />
        <result property="email" column="email" />
        <result property="password" column="password" />
        <result property="birthDate" column="birth_date" />
        <result property="gender" column="gender" />
        <result property="isAccountNonExpired" column="is_account_non_expired" />
        <result property="isAccountNonLocked" column="is_account_non_locked" />
        <result property="isCredentialsNonExpired" column="is_credentials_non_expired" />
        <result property="isEnabled" column="is_enabled" />
        <result property="lastLoginDate" column="last_login_date" />
        <result property="createDate" column="create_date" />
        <result property="lastUpdateDate" column="last_update_date" />

        <!-- Role fields -->
        <collection property="authorities" ofType="com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.RoleView" javaType="java.util.List">
            <id property="roleId" column="role_id" />
            <result property="roleName" column="role_name" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findAll" resultMap="userRoleResultMap">
        SELECT u.*, r.*
        FROM tbl_user u
                 INNER JOIN tbl_role_user_map ur ON u.username = ur.username
                 INNER JOIN tbl_role r ON ur.role_id = r.role_id
    </select>


</mapper>

this is my jave code for
user view
package com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserView implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String gender;
    private Boolean isAccountNonExpired;
    private Boolean isAccountNonLocked;
    private Boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
    private Boolean isEnabled;
    private Date lastLoginDate;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date lastUpdateDate;
    private List<RoleView> authorities;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities.stream().map(auth -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getRoleName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.isAccountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return this.isAccountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.isCredentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.isEnabled;
    }
}


Role view
package com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RoleView {
    private Long roleId;
    private String roleName;
}


and UserService
package com.example.learningspringsecurity.controller.service;

import com.example.learningspringsecurity.dao.RoleRepository;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.dao.UserMapper;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.dto.RegisterDto;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.dto.UserInfoDto;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.RoleUserMappingView;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.RoleView;
import com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.UserView;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;


    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<UserInfoDto> findAllUsers() {
        List<UserView> users = userMapper.findAll();
        return users.stream().map(this::userToUserInfoDto).toList();
    }

    public void createUser(RegisterDto user) {
        UserView userView = UserView.builder()
                .username(user.username())
                .email(user.email())
                .password(user.password())
                .birthDate(user.birthDate())
                .gender(user.gender())
                .createDate(new Date())
                .isAccountNonLocked(true)
                .isAccountNonExpired(true)
                .isCredentialsNonExpired(true)
                .isEnabled(true)
                .lastLoginDate(null)
                .lastUpdateDate(null)
                .build();
        int result = userMapper.insertUser(userView);
        if(result == 1) {
            RoleView role = roleRepository.GetRoleByName("ROLE_USER");
            result = roleRepository.AddRoleUserMap(RoleUserMappingView.builder()
                    .roleId(role.getRoleId())
                    .username(userView.getUsername())
                    .build()
            );
            if(result != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Insert to role user failed");
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    private UserInfoDto userToUserInfoDto(UserView user) {
        return new UserInfoDto(
                 user.getUsername()
                ,user.getEmail()
                ,user.getBirthDate()
                ,user.getGender()
        );

    }
}

and my error log
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:77)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyConstructorAutomapping(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:780)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createByConstructorSignature(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:727)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:689)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:659)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:440)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForNestedResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:1026)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:335)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:310)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:158)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:110)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:90)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:425)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy69.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy75.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.learningspringsecurity.controller.service.UserService.findAllUsers(UserService.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at com.example.learningspringsecurity.controller.service.UserService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findAllUsers(<generated>)
    at com.example.learningspringsecurity.controller.AuthTestController.noAuth(AuthTestController.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)



as i am not a english speaker. if my wring cause you troule. please forgive me. thank you

What does the UserMapper do?

@3DKS The easiest solution is to add @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor to both UserView and RoleView. You can specify access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE if you prefer.

Maybe the problem is the conversion between the SQL DateTime(6) and the java.util.Date? If you put the attribute "resultType"="java.util.Date" on the result elements in your rowmapper which relate to Dates then you might flush out the issue before it gets to the constructor.
If I were you I would debug org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass and inspect the params which are being sent to the constructor.

Unrelatedly, your username field has a size of 100 in one table and a size of 255 in another which is a problem for joins.

Thank for your comment. i will try it when i complete current project. thank you all again.

In the userview and Role View I have added the @AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor then the issue is fixed. thank you ave, thank you all
package com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security;

import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RoleView {
    private Long roleId;
    private String roleName;
}


package com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserView implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String gender;
    private Boolean isAccountNonExpired;
    private Boolean isAccountNonLocked;
    private Boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
    private Boolean isEnabled;
    private Date lastLoginDate;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date lastUpdateDate;
    private List<RoleView> authorities;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities.stream().map(auth -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getRoleName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.isAccountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return this.isAccountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.isCredentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.isEnabled;
    }
}


I have not been able to reproduce your problem yet due to not having a sample MyBatis project: however, I think your issue is due to the fact that you are specifying the javaType of your collection as java.util.List, which is an abstract type. The example of this sort of collection using a join with repeated rows in the MyBatis documentation does not specify the javaType of the collection, and indeed remarks

The javaType attribute is really unnecessary, as MyBatis will figure this out for you in most cases.

So I recommend trying your collection without the javaType element:
    <!-- Role fields -->
    <collection property="authorities" 
            ofType="com.example.learningspringsecurity.view.security.RoleView">
        <id property="roleId" column="role_id" />
        <result property="roleName" column="role_name" />
    </collection>


thank for your comment, i will try it when i complete current job. thank you again.
